# looping json data in Jquery on KeyPair base

Tags: java, jquery, html, json, spring

Hi Guys below is the response i'm getting from server. I tried to loop it based on keys unfortunately i was not successful.

```
{"metricsLevelList": [{
"levelName": "Account1Name",
"levelId": 1,
"metrics":    [
        {
     "value": "80",
     "greenZoneStart": "90",
     "greenZoneEnd": "100",
     "yellowZoneStart": "60",
     "yellowZoneEnd": "90",
     "redZoneStart": "0",
     "redZoneEnd": "60",
     "metricsType": "Dial",
     "metricsName": "FTR Deliverables"
  },
        {
     "value": "0",
     "greenZoneStart": "90",
     "greenZoneEnd": "100",
     "yellowZoneStart": "60",
     "yellowZoneEnd": "90",
     "redZoneStart": "0",
     "redZoneEnd": "60",
     "metricsType": "Dial",
     "metricsName": "OTD Deliverables"
  },
        {
     "value": "0",
     "greenZoneStart": "0",
     "greenZoneEnd": "5",
     "yellowZoneStart": "5",
     "yellowZoneEnd": "15",
     "redZoneStart": "15",
     "redZoneEnd": "100",
     "metricsType": "Dial",
     "metricsName": "% Defect Rejection"
  },
        {
     "value": null,
     "greenZoneStart": null,
     "greenZoneEnd": null,
     "yellowZoneStart": null,
     "yellowZoneEnd": null,
     "redZoneStart": null,
     "redZoneEnd": null,
     "metricsType": null,
     "metricsName": null
  },
        {
     "value": "0",
     "greenZoneStart": "90",
     "greenZoneEnd": "100",
     "yellowZoneStart": "70",
     "yellowZoneEnd": "90",
     "redZoneStart": "0",
     "redZoneEnd": "70",
     "metricsType": "Dial",
     "metricsName": "CSAT (% VoC)"
  }
]
}]}
```

Here i have to loop metricsLevelList (where i will have different level names) inside that another loop for metrics(which have metrics content). Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following loop to iterate the nested objects(assume your json is stored in variable called jsonDemo):

```
function loop(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if(val && typeof val === "object") { // object, call recursively
            console.log(" "); 
            loop(val);
        } else {
            console.log(key + "-->" + obj[key]); 
        }
    });
}

loop(jsonDemo);
```

See the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/pgo637dj/"

Explanation: This will iterate over all the keys of the object and check whether each key is further an object, if so it will recursively call it else it will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer after lot of trail and errors

```
var responseEle =${response};
var importantObject = responseEle.metricsLevelList[0];
for (var item in importantObject) {
var theDate = item; //the KEY
var theNumber = importantObject[item]; //the VALUE
if(item =='metrics')
{
$.each(theNumber, function(i, newItem){

});
}
}
```